# MVVMCross 5.3.2 UWP: Where to Get IMvxWindowsFrame for MvxFormsUwpViewPresenter

Tags: windows, xamarin, mvvmcross, frame

I'm working out of the Xamarin Forms for MVVMCross 5 Solution Template and updated the packages to the latest version (5.3.2 for MVVMCross). Doing that changes some namespaces around particularly in the UWP project.

It seems that I need to resolve IMvxViewPresenter as MvxFormsUwpViewPresenter which takes a IMvxWindowsFrame as an argument. In the setup file method of Setup.cs there's a XamlControls.Frame rootFrame passed as an argument but I'm not sure if that's suppose to be cast somehow as IMvxWindowsFrame.

Where can you pull the object that implements IMvxWindowsFrame from or is there another way to turn the rootFrame into an IMvxWindowsFrame legitimately.

```
public class Setup : MvxFormsWindowsSetup
{
    private readonly LaunchActivatedEventArgs _launchActivatedEventArgs;

    public Setup(XamlControls.Frame rootFrame, LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) : base(rootFrame, e)
    {
        _launchActivatedEventArgs = e;


        // Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxWindowsFrame>(rootFrame);
    }

    protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
    {
        base.InitializeFirstChance();

        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<Core.Services.ILocalizeService>(new Services.LocalizeService());
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ISettings>(CrossSettings.Current);


        Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxViewPresenter, MvxFormsUwpViewPresenter>();
    }

    protected override MvxFormsApplication CreateFormsApplication()
    {
        return new Core.FormsApp();
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new Core.MvxApp();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new Core.DebugTrace();
    }
}

    public sealed partial class MainPage : WindowsPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        start.Start();

        var presenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsUwpViewPresenter;
        LoadApplication(presenter.FormsApplication);

        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've been looking more into the class MvxFormsWindowsSetup in the source code at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross-Forms/MvvmCross.Forms.Uwp/Platform/MvxFormsWindowsSetup.cs. It appears that in the method CreateViewPresenter that the IMvxViewPresenter is registered as a singleton with the MvxWrappedFrame already inside but by default the code does not resolve when calling var presenter = Mvx.Resolve() as MvxFormsUwpViewPresenter; in the windows page. Possible bug? Trying to see if I can resolve it myself.

Looks like it fails to resolve even if I put the code right after when Mvx is suppose to register the type / singleton

```
 protected override IMvxWindowsViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter(IMvxWindowsFrame rootFrame)
    {
        var presenter = new MvxFormsUwpViewPresenter(rootFrame, FormsApplication);
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxFormsViewPresenter>(presenter);
        var presenter2 = Mvx.GetSingleton<IMvxViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsUwpViewPresenter;
        return presenter;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are trying to do. Resolve `IMvxFormsViewPresenter` should work, why would you resolve `IMvxViewPresenter` then?

Comment: Yeah I just realized that about 2 minutes ago. That was the correct answer. In 5.1.1 which the Starter package defaults to it resolves IMvxViewPresenter but in 5.3.2 it needs to be IMvxFormsViewPresenter.

Answer (score 0):

When updating to MvvmCross 5.3.2 for UWP, the presenter needs to resolve as IMvxFormsViewPresenter rather than IMvxViewPresenter. Change the interface type and it should load properly.

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        start.Start();

        var presenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFormsViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsUwpViewPresenter;

        LoadApplication(presenter.FormsApplication);

        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    }
```